# how to print List of Objects inside Object in Thymleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have Java object as below:

```
public class Bean {
    private String className;
    private List<Property> properties;
}

public class Property {

    private String name;
    private String val;
    public Property(String name, String val) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

I have a `List<Bean>` as below:

**How to show Bean class Name with it's properties name and value pairs in html list?**

example output I'm able to achieve using code following it: 
[image]

```
List<Bean> staticBeans = /* assume */
model.addAttribute("staticBeans", staticBeans);

<ol>
        <li th:each="staticBean,i: ${staticBeans}">
               <div th:text="*{staticBeans[__${i.index}__].className}" /></div>
                <ul th:each="prp,j: ${staticBean.properties}">
                    <li><div th:text="*{staticBeans[__${i.index}__].properties[__${j.index}__].val}" > </div></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

is there a better way to index the properties.val. I don't know how to make use of prp and make indexing short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use preprocessing when you are simply printing out values.  The code should look something like:

```
<ol>
    <li th:each="bean: ${staticBeans}">
        <div th:text="${bean.className}" /></div>

        <ul th:each="property: ${bean.properties}">
            <li th:text="${property.val}" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```